# What is a "fangirl moment"?

Tags: culture, meme

So I found this image highlighting the difference between an Otaku and a Weeaboo.

[image: Otaku VS Weeaboo]

The 4th point says

> Has "fangirl moments" at anytime, anywhere, and infront of anyone

But what are "fangirl moments"? and what are their origin? (Is it actually from anime)

Comment: well I guess it would be an uncontrolled reaction to some thing exiting about the anime or what they are a fan of. like a fangirl seeing her favorite actor or singer and screaming out of joy and excitement without considering the surroundings.

Comment: The way it's used in that image, it's purposely vague so you can imagine whatever kind of behaviour would annoy you and make the image creator's point for them.

Comment: have to say, this distinction only exists within the community encompassing these two. from the outside they're both the same except one is a closet weeaboo lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Fangirls](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fangirl) have been around for quite a while. The term having it's first recorded use in 1934 in the [novel by humorist A. P. Herbert called Holy Deadlock](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10015082-holy-deadlock) which is about the struggles of a divorce. The first behavior which now a days is commonly described as Fangirl-moment or Fangirling is also used in this book, effectively making it the origin of the term.

Fangirls are closely related to [Fanboys](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fanboy), which is the male edition of fangirls, which has been around since 1919.

A [Fangirl-moment](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fangirl%20moment) or sometimes called [fangirling](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fangirling) usually occurs when a subject of interest is mentioned, or comes closely related to current topics. There from out they will either

1. waste endless amounts of time ogling, discussing/arguing, stalking, etc. the object of their "affection"

   or
2. React with shortness of breath, fainting, highpitched noises, shaking, fierce head shaking as if in the midst of a seizure, wet panties, endless blog posts, etc.

All though the terms themselves aren't that old, the *behavior* it self is. [Idolization](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/idolization) has been around since the 1590's where rulers, kings and the likes where Idolized and probably had quite some *fangirls* fangirling as well.